# Existence of limit of a function of a complex variable.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Say that I have a function $f(z)=f(x+iy)=f(x,y)$ and I want to investigate whether the limit at a particular point, say $z=0$ exists.

I recall that within the domain of real numbers, I checked whether the "right" and "left" limits were the same.

Now is it possible to do this in a similar way when $z$ is complex?
e.g. Is it enough to let $z = re^{i \phi}$ and check whether the limit when $r$ goes to $0$ is independent of $\phi$?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in $\mathbb{C}$ (or really $\mathbb{R}^2$ here) it won't be enough to check any particular "direction". You have to handle a general sequence.

For an counterexample, consider (very discontinuous) function $f$, such that $f(1/n, 1/n^2) = 1$ but for all other arguments $f(x,y) = 0$. Then clearly limit of $f$ does not exist at $0$, but for any fixed $\phi$ you have $f(r e^{i\phi}) = 0$, except for at most one value of $r$.

That being said, by passing to subsequences, you can generally assume that $x_n \to 0$ either from above or from below, and likewise for $y$. More generally, if you partition $\mathbb{C}$ into finitely many pieces, you can work with sequences whose all elements fall into one piece.

Comment: Ok, thank you! But what if I already know that f is continuous everywhere except at (0,0)?

Comment: @iolo: That won't help much, but giving an example becomes more mundane then. The general idea is that instead of putting $f(z_n) = 1$ at some points and $f(z) = 0$ elsewhere, you but a "bump function" at $z_n$, so that: (1) $f(z_n) = 1$ (2) $f(z) = 0$ if $|z-z_n| > r_n$ for all $n$ (here, $r_n$ is some small radius, $r_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$) (3) in the area $\{ |z-z_n| < r_n\}$, $f$ "gently" goes from $1$ to $0$. Constructions like that can give you very smooth functions.